# Can't Call Flash AS3 Function From JavaScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I'm extremely confused, I've taken a whole day to do something that should be very easy. I just want to call a Flash function from JavaScript - that's it.

ActionScript Code:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.net.FileReference;             
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.system.Security;

Security.allowDomain("*");
ExternalInterface.addCallback("test", test);

function test()
{
    ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Doesn't Work");
}
```

JavaScript/HTML

```
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <script>
        function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
            var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
            return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
        }
        function poc() {
            getFlashMovie( "Test" ).test();
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="poc()">Click Me!</button>
```

This doesn't work, the function 'test' does not exist for object 'Test'

I thought I'd ask here as a last ditch effort. Here's my live example:
http://itsclassified.info/flash/Test.html

Comment: use `document.getElementById("Test")` to get the reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some js code of the given page http://itsclassified.info/flash/Test.html

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Test.swf" name="POC" width="1" height="1">
                <param name="movie" value="Test.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
```

Try to change

```
name="POC"
```

to

```
name="Test"
```

I have test  it in chrome and IE11, it works.